# Eloquent where clause returning wrong entries

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, lumen

In my Laravel/Lumen Project (Version 8) I try to retrieve data from my Oracle Database, but I get unexpected data.

My database contains following 4 entries:

| ID | FOREIGN_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Entry1 |
| 2 | 100 | Entry2 |
| 3 | 100 | Entry3 |
| 4 | 200 | Entry4 |

My model:

```
class Entry extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'MyConnection';
    protected $table = 'MY_TABLE';
    protected $fillable = ['foreign_id', 'name'];
    protected $hidden =  ['foreign_id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'foreign_id' => 'integer'
    ];
}
```

When I execute the following line of code, only Entry1 with ID 1 is returned, while I would expect an empty collection:

```
Entry::where([['id', '!=', 1], 'foreign_id' => 100, 'name' => 'Entry1'])->get();
```

To analyze the problem, I also tried to write lined up where clauses:

```
//returns all but Entry1; correct
Entry::where(['id', '!=', 1])->get();

//returns Entry2 and Entry3; correct
Entry::where(['id', '!=', 1])->where(['foreign_id' => 100])->get(); 

//returns only Entry1; wrong, should be an empty collection
Entry::where(['id', '!=', 1])->where(['foreign_id' => 100])->where(['name' => 'Entry1'])->get();
```

The generated sql query looks like this:

```
"select * from "MY_TABLE" where ("ID" != ? and "FOREIGN_ID" = ? and "NAME" = ?)"
```

The Lumen Version is: 8.3.4

EDIT:

I have tried this on another Laptop now. There I get an empty collection.
Have you any idea what configuration/setting might do the trick, that my query is interpreted in two different ways?

EDIT 2:

It seems that switching from "!=" to "not like" fixed the issue. But don't ask me why.

Comment: Which one? The last one?
If yes, thats exactly my problem. I expect an empty collection, but get Entry1

Comment: `->where->(['name' => 'Entry1'])` is a typo?

Comment: What does the generated SQL query look like?

Comment: the ->toSql() returns following string:
"select * from "MY_TABLE" where ("ID" != ? and "FOREIGN_ID" = ? and "NAME" = ?)"

When I put in the values and execute the query in my SqlDeveloper it works correctly.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the exact (copy/paste) query you get? Also show us which version of the query builder example you used to get that exact query?

Comment: have you tried with the other entries? for example Entry::where(['id', '!=', 2])->where(['foreign_id' => 100])->where(['name' => 'Entry2'])->get(); 
because ive been reading that code and tested it using my own database and it works as intended (returns empty array) so perhaps there is an other Entry1?

Comment: The data in the database is correctly. The entry only exists once, and the same thing happens with other entries

Comment: What about raw query? perhaps some issue with oracle or eloquent

Comment: what do you mean by "raw query"? Isn't my edit in the question the thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

```
Entry::where([
['id', '!=', 1], 
['foreign_id', 100], 
['name', 'Entry1']
])->get();
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Hello @Febertson Actually Using your data (records), 1st you find  ('id', '!=', 1) means details are remaining 2,3, and 4 like (Entry2, Entry3, Entry4). Then after you can not get any details so you got Empty collection

Comment: If you want to get Collection then remove your ID not equal to 1, then you will get

Comment: They're expecting an empty array, so removing the id != 1 defies that purpose if im not mistaken

Comment: I cant remove the id check, because it is needed in my code.

Comment: Okay @Febertson Then change Name  like Entry2 and check it

Answer (score -1):

```
Entry::where(['foreign_id' => 100,'name' => 'Entry1'])
->where('id', '!=', 1)
->get();
```